# g:While loop not working

Tags: while-loop

Still getting use to this grails stuff :)

I have a while loop thats not working and I cant firgure out why

```
    <g:set var="idx" value="1"/>
    <td>ZZZZZ ${idx}</td> <!-- this prints with value of 1-->
    <g:while test="${idx<10}">
        <g:set var="idx" value="${idx+1}"/>
        <th>Wk+${idx}</th><!-- this never prints -->
    </g:while>

</tr>
```

I cant seem to find the issue, I've also tried change value to expr in the

thanks

Answer (score 0):

After i did this

```
<g:set var="idx" value="${1}"/>
```

it started to work